# Is there like python monthcalendar method in c#?

Tags: c#, python

I want to convert a python code to c# code,in python code there is a method that name is `calendar.monthcalendar(year,month)` I don't know how can i convert it c# code.

> monthcalendar() method
>
> The monthrange() method is used to get a matrix representing a month’s
>   calendar.  Each row represents a week; days outside of the month a
>   represented by zeros.  Each week begins with Monday unless set by
>   setfirstweekday().

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing in c#. Maybe a good open source project for you.

Comment: Yeah, it should be easy to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static int[,] MonthCalendar(int year, int month, DayOfWeek firstWeekDay)
{
    int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    DayOfWeek first = new DateTime(year, month, 1).DayOfWeek;
    int left = ((int)first - (int)firstWeekDay + 7) % 7;
    int[,] arr = new int[7, (left + daysInMonth + 6) / 7];
    for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++)
    {
        int a = left + i;
        arr[a % 7, a / 7] = i + 1;
    }
    return arr;
}

static void Test(int year, int month, DayOfWeek firstWeekDay)
{
    string[] week = new string[]{ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    Console.WriteLine(year + "-" + month);
    for (int i = (int)firstWeekDay; i < ((int)firstWeekDay + 7); i++)
    {
        Console.Write(" " + week[i % 7]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    var arr = MonthCalendar(year, month, firstWeekDay);
    for (int y = 0; y < arr.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[x, y].ToString().PadLeft(4));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

`Test(2017, 12, DayOfWeek.Monday);` output:

```
2017-12
 Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
   0   0   0   0   1   2   3
   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```